# Understanding phishing/basic internet security guide, for teens?

Tags: internet-security, phishing

I just helped a 13 year-old relative set up a new Windows 7 desktop, making it as secure as I can remember knowing how to.

I has been an hour, and he just came to me saying "I seem to have a virus.".  It was a website scam showing the big "You have a virus! ====== scan 100% complete.", with clever pop-ups and javascript, with the standard "clicking to close the window tries to install software" situation.  Very good facsimile of a virus alert that has probably caught many adults.

I explained a little, and searched for some resources for explaining phishing and/or good software install policies, but didn't find much useful (other than a single corporately-bland youtube video).

So, anyone aware of any useful resources out there for conveying this tricky security issue?

Comment: sounds like someone needs to make a "Don't Copy That Floppy" video for internet security basics

Comment: http://www.onguardonline.gov/topics/phishing.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alison Gianotto (@snipeyhead on Twitter) has a good basic presentation meant for small companies available on one of her sites. http://www.snipe.net/2011/01/security-keynote/

It's a good overview at a non-technical level of all the "bad things" that can happen on the internet.

Alison is mildly-NSFW, however if your relative is old enough to surf the web unaccompanied, they're old enough for this document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice.  Maybe he'll be receptive to that.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [video explaining phishing scams](http://www.youtube.com/user/leelefever#p/u/7/sqRZGhiHGxg) in a clear, simple way with drawings and audio. It's mostly targeted at banking customers, and talks a lot about credit cards and banking details, but the lessons explained in it apply to other forms of online activities.

[image: screenshot from video]

Comment: Could you please add some more details about what this is and how it might be helpful?

Comment: Plaintext video of phishing, somewhat specifically email and bank phishing, unfortunately, doesn't get into the idea of website phishing at all.  Teen's not really going to deal with banking much.

Comment: @Tchalvak I know what's in it; I watched it. I'm hoping that @aimar will edit his answer to be a bit more useful. We discourage bare links without explanation. If you'd like, you could suggest an edit to the answer yourself, but I am trying to encourage the new user to write better answers.

Comment: @nhinkle: I've tried to "enhance" my answer , hope you like it this way :)

Comment: thanks for updating your post! Your update was a definite imporvement. I went ahead and made a few more changes, as an example of the sorts of explanation, formatting, and content we look for in great posts.